# use sed to merge lines and add comma

Tags: bash, sed

I found several related questions, but none of them fits what I need, and since I am a real beginner, I can't figure it out.

I have a text file with entries like this, separated by a blank line:

```
example entry &with/ special characters
next line (any characters)

next %*entry
more words
```

I would like the output merge the lines, put a comma between, and delete empty lines. I.e., the example should look like this:

```
example entry &with/ special characters, next line (any characters)
next %*entry, more words
```

I would prefer sed, because I know it a little bit, but am also happy about any other solution on the linux command line.

Comment: Should commas in the data be disambiguated in the output somehow?

Comment: So is an empty line an entry separator, or do you always have exactly two lines which should be joined together?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Improved per Kent's elegant suggestion:**

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="";FS="\n";OFS=","}{$1=$1}7' file
```

which allows any number of lines per block, rather than the 2 rigid lines per block I had. Thank you,  Kent. **Note**: The `7` is Kent's trademark... any non-zero expression will cause `awk` to print the entire record, and he likes `7`.

You can do this with `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="";FS="\n";OFS=","}{print $1,$2}' file
```

That sets the record separator to blank lines, the field separator to newlines and the output field separator to a comma.

**Output:**

```
example entry &with/ special characters,next line (any characters)
next %*entry,more words
```

Comment: +1 however after the `BEGIN` block, I would do `... '{$1=$1}7' file` for the cases that in a "block" there are more than two lines.

Comment: op wants `space` after comma.

Comment: Your code should be `awk 'BEGIN{RS="";FS="\n";OFS=", "}{print $1,$2}'`

Answer (score 2):

Simple `sed` command,

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/, /g;s/, , /\n/g' file
```

- `:a;N;$!ba;s/\n/, /g` -> According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1252191/3297613) answer, this code replaces all the new lines with `,`(comma and space).
- So After running only the first command, the output would be

  ```
  example entry &with/ special characters, next line (any characters), , next %*entry, more words
  ```
- `s/, , /\n/g` - > Replacing `, ,` with new line in the above output will give you the desired result.

  ```
  example entry &with/ special characters, next line (any characters)
  next %*entry, more words
  ```

Comment: you have to treat the case where there is `, , ` into the text or`, ` at the end of one line. if not occuring, your code is fast and simple

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;$!N;/.\n./s/\n/, /;ta;/^[^\n]/P;D' file
```

Append the next line to the current line and if there are characters either side of the newline substitute the newline with a comma and a space and then repeat. Eventually an empty line or the end-of-file will be reached, then only print the next line if it is not empty.

Another version but a little more sofisticated (allowing for white space in the empty line) would be:

```
sed ':a;$!N;/^\s*$/M!s/\n/, /;ta;/\`\s*$/M!P;D' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n '1h;1!H
$ {x
   s/\([^[:cntrl:]]\)\n\([^[:cntrl:]]\)/\1, \2/g
   s/\(\n\)\n\{1,\}/\1/g
   p
   }' YourFile
```

change all after loading file in buffer. Could be done "on the fly" while reading the file and based on empty  line or not.

use `-e` on GNU sed